# IE9 misbehavior with object array

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsp, extjs, lso

My JS code works perfectly fine in all browsers except IE.

I am not sure why this is happening, the obeserved behavior is

```
Ext.Msg.alert(filterIds.length) -> gives 2.

Ext.Msg.alert(Object.prototype.toString.call(filterIds)) -> object Array

Ext.Msg.alert(filterIds) -> prints nothing

Ext.Msg.alert(filterIds.toString()) -> alert box doesn show up, hence I was assuming it is giving error.
```

This doesn happen the first time I am accesing the variable, afterwards this behavior begins. Is it my mistake ?

Thanks

PS: I am using Ext-js 3.4.

On using debug mode I get message like 
SCRIPT5011: Can't execute code from a freed script for

```
Ext.Msg.alert(filterIds.toString())
```

Also this on local variables. 
    [+]     filterIds   [0] Object, (Array)
    [+]     [0] "0" String
    [+]     [1] "2" String

Comment: Press F12 and check your console for errors or messages. Please share them here.

Comment: It is working perfectly if I am changin it to array of integers, why do you think this is not be working for object arrays of string ?

Comment: Can you please upload a small example of this behavior?